# Logging execution time with cppunit

Tags: cppunit

I am doing unit testing with cppunit library. I need to log the execution time for each tests. Is there any way to log the execution time in the XML file? Can someone point me to some examples? My code is below. I want the execution time in the xml file results_cppunit.xml

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    TestResult result;
    TestResultCollector resultCollector;
    result.addListener(&resultCollector);

    TextUi::TestRunner runner;
    runner.addTest(TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest());
    runner.run(result);

    ofstream xmlFileOut("results_cppunit.xml");
    XmlOutputter xmlOut(&resultCollector, xmlFileOut);
    xmlOut.write();

    return resultCollector.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CppUnit::TestResult has an addListener method. You can add a subclass of CppUnit::TestListener that just logs the time of the test by overwriting startTest and endTest.

You can see an example for that in the [Libreoffice source code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/sal/cppunittester/cppunittester.cxx#n87).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @moggi. Getting the execution time was not the real problem, Putting that value in the xml file was the problem. I have updated the question with my code. Could you check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using both TestListener and XmlOutputterHook. TestListener  to log the execution time and XmlOutputterHook to insert it into xml.